# Why is my Google Analytics Code Getting edited when I enter it into Blogger?

Tags: html, google-analytics, statistics, blogger

After getting the needed code from Google Analytics (see below) I am entering it just before the  tag in the HTML from my settings. However it CHANGES every time after I save to the garbage below with #39 tag. Why is it doing this? What can I do?

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-46134833-1', 'ourunitedvoice.org');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>

<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#39;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#39;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,&#39;script&#39;,&#39;//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#39;,&#39;ga&#39;);
ga(&#39;create&#39;, &#39;UA-46134833-1&#39;, &#39;ourunitedvoice.org&#39;);
ga(&#39;send&#39;, &#39;pageview&#39;);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 #39
```

is an encoded quotation mark (it seem Blogger what's to prevent you from breaking your template).

I have never used blogger but there should be no need to enter any code. [According to documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009610?hl=en) all you have to do os to enter you Analytics account id in the appropriate tab.